# Set response header in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, filter, browser-cache, response-headers, no-cache

How can I set the response header for each call in my application made with Spring Boot?
I would like to try to use a filter to intercept all the calls and be able to set the response header.
I followed the guide [Disable browser caching HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401531/disable-browser-caching-html5/49402824#49402824), but only set the request header, and not always.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Set the response for a specific controller, in the Controller class:

```java
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = DEFAULT_ADMIN_URL + "/xxx/")
    public class XxxController
    ....
        @ModelAttribute
        public void setResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
           response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
           ....
        }
```

or

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/find/employer/{employerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List getEmployees(@PathVariable("employerId") Long employerId, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return employeeService.findEmployeesForEmployer(employerId);
    }
```

2. Or you can put the response header for **each** call in the application (this is for Spring annotation-based, otherwise see [automatically add header to every response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190699/automatically-add-header-to-every-response)):

```java
    @Component
    public class Filter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    ....
     @Override
     protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
     }
    }
```

3. The last way I found is using an Interceptor that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter; for more info see https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-handlerinterceptor-annotation-example-webmvcconfigureradapter

- create your Interceptor that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter:

```java
    public class HeaderInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    
      @Override
      public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object handler) {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1.
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
        return true;
      }
    }
```

- In your MvcConfig thath extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter you must Override the addInterceptors method and add new Interceptor:

```java
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        ....
        registry.addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor());
    }
```

I hope I was helpful!

Comment: Option 2 is the best! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Filter and is registered by `@Component` annotation. The `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`  is used for Advice execution precedence.

```
 @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public class NoCacheWebFilter implements Filter {
       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NoCacheWebFilter.class);


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.debug("Initiating WebFilter >> ");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new 
                    HeaderMapRequestWrapper(req);
            // implement you logic to add header
            //requestWrapper.addHeader("remote_addr", "");
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response); 

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        logger.debug("Destroying WebFilter >> ");
    }
    }
```