# Add response header in HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: spring, header, interceptor

I am adding a header to the response inside `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.
However it seems that the response header cannot be modified in the `postHandle` method.

```
public class CredentialInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Object handler,ModelAndView modelAndView) {
            String value = "...";
            response.addHeader("header_name",value ); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

**How to add a header to the response ?**

Popular solution is to use `OncePerRequestFilter` ( [Set response header in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430853/set-response-header-in-spring-boot/49431665#49431665) ). Isn't there any other way ?

Comment: If the response has already (partially) been send you cannot change it, this is already very likely in the case of the `postHandle` method. You can do it in the `preHandle` as that is before the response has been send. Using a filter (and doing it after the call to `chain.doFilter`) would yield the same result.

Comment: @M.Deinum , doing it in `preHandle` solved the problem. You comment is already the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with adding headers in the `postHandle` method is that the response may already be (partially) send. When that is the case you cannot add/change headers anymore. You need to set the headers before anything is sent to the client.

This you can do in the `preHandle` method or more generic a servlet filter before you call `filterchain.doFilter`. Doing it after the aforementioned call you might get the same issue that a response has already (partially) been sent.