# HandleInterceptor Response Header null

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I have implemented the following interceptor to test setting a header on my request and then my response.

```
@RestController
public class SpringController {
    @PostMapping(value="/test")
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class ControllerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Pre-handle");
        System.out.println(request.getHeader("RequestId"));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        response.setHeader("ResponseId", "2");
        System.out.println("Post-handle");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        response.addHeader("ResponseId", "2");
        System.out.println(response.getHeader("ResponseId"));
        System.out.println("After completion");
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class ControllerInterceptorAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ControllerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

When i insert a RequestId header in Postman, i can see it's value in the terminal as shown below:

```
Pre-handle
1
Post-handle
null
After completion
```

But the ResponseId header value is null on the terminal and does not even appear in Postman reponse. How should i set the ResponseId header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the response header too late, in the `postHandle()` and `afterCompletion()` methods the response could already be sent.

Add the headers in the `preHandle()` method instead.

Someone else had a similar problem here: [Add response header in HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409560/add-response-header-in-handlerinterceptoradapter)

Comment: This worked but i have to ask, if modifying the response header is done in preHandle, what stuff is postHandle used for?

Comment: for example to add attributes to `ModelAndView` or to measure the processing time of the request